# Using correct datatypes in SQL and creating child tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, parent-child, ms-access-2010, sqldatatypes

Super noob here at my wits end with Access 2010. I have some questions:

How do I create a child table in Access? I figured it'd be just a matter of defining the PK in the child table then referencing that PK as a FK to the parent table. Here's my sql code just in case I'm not making a bit of sense:

This is the end of my parent table which is Employee-

```
    CONSTRAINT  PKEmployee  PRIMARY  KEY  (EmpNo) ,
    CONSTRAINT  FKPosNo FOREIGN KEY  (PosNo)  REFERENCES  Position,  
    CONSTRAINT FKDeptNo FOREIGN KEY (DeptNo) REFERENCES Department )
```

Here's what I have for my child table, which is Salary. It's an Employee type-

```
    CREATE TABLE Salary
    (     EmpNo                 CHAR (6) ,
          OfficeNo              CHAR (4) ,
          SalaryAmount            DOUBLE ,
    CONSTRAINT PKEmpNo PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
    CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee )
```

When I run this code is gives me the "There is already a relationship named 'FKEmpNo' in the database." message. I'm not sure if this is on my end or Access'.

I'm also getting a syntax error when I try to declare 'SalaryAmount' as a DECIMAL. My code for it is:

```
  (EmpNo                 CHAR (6) ,
  OfficeNo              CHAR (4) ,
  SalaryAmount      DECIMAL (7, 2) ,
  CONSTRAINT PKEmpNo PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo),
  CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee )
```

The error highlights the first parenthesis. Can I even use DECIMAL type in access 2010? If not, what is the best way to represent a yearly income in Access 2010?

Please provide examples and explain to me like I'm a five year old. I'm trying wrap my mind around this database stuff without losing it.

Comment: You must have a constraint named `FKEmpNo` in some other table.

Comment: I do. And I planned on referencing EmpNo in numerous tables. Can I not have that for some reason? How am I to use EmpNo as a foreign key in more than one table then? Thanks

Comment: Just name the constraint something different.  I usually use a combination of the constraint type (FK, UC...), the table name and the field name(s)

Comment: Use names like `FKSalarayEmpNo` to distinguish the foreign key constraints from different tables.

Comment: I think Access might have a "currency" datatype... could you use that?  I'm trying to google why `SalaryAmount DECIMAL (7, 2),` is incorrect but I don't know.  Maybe the comma is unnecessary?  Can you provide the whole statement?

Comment: Are you sure it's `decimal` and not `numeric (7,2)`.  (I'm trying to google this for you but not having much luck)  **EDIT:** According to **[this ms access 2010 documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-HA010341783.aspx)** there is no "decimal" datatype...?

Comment: -Gloomy I edited my post with the whole statement. You are running into the same trouble I am. I can't seem to find clear cut answers about anything sql-acess related. And -Barmar, I didn't realize you could do that. Thank you both very much.

Comment: actually... i might be wrong about the documentation.. I don't know. yes, whole statement please... put it in your post up there and format it.

Comment: What method are you using to execute that `CREATE TABLE` which includes the `DECIMAL` field type?

Comment: Most people find that the UI is easier to use.  Is there any reason that you are trying to do this via DDL/SQL instead of the designer?

Comment: -HansUp Sorry, I guess the CREATE TABLE Salary didn't get posted for the first line, so yes it is a CREATE TABLE statement.  -tgolisch This is for a school project and my professor requires SQL statements. He did say that they don't need to actually create the tables but must be syntactically correct. I might use the UI if I just can't get the tables created using SQL.

Comment: I don't think there is a decimal datatype.  Just use `currency` or double.  I tried to test this with VBA and Access 2007.  It works for with currency but not decimal.  On the front end of Access, it didn't give me an option for decimal there, either.  (oh, wait, I can do a `number` datatype and that gives me an option for decimal, but it's not the same)

Comment: @BenignBaboon A `CREATE TABLE` with `DECIMAL` must be executed from ADO.  It will not work when you attempt to execute the statement from DAO.  If you're doing this from the Access query designer, be aware the query designer uses DAO "under the hood".  All that aside, seems to me that `CURRENCY` would be the natural choice for a SalaryAmount field --- it's money, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample below builds and executes this statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Salary
    (
        uid COUNTER PRIMARY KEY,
        EmpNo CHAR (6),
        OfficeNo CHAR (4),
        SalaryAmount DECIMAL (7, 2),
        CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee(EmpNo)
    );
```

It successfully created the table with `SalaryAmount DECIMAL (7, 2)` because the statement was executed from `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`, which is an ADO method.  You can only use `DECIMAL` in a `CREATE TABLE` when it's executed from ADO.  It will not work when executed with DAO.  The query designer uses DAO to execute queries.

If Access complains about a name clash with an existing *FKEmpNo* constraint, use a different name for the foreign key constraint --- one which doesn't match any other existing constraint ...

```sql
CONSTRAINT BobIsYourUncle FOREIGN KEY ...
```

Note I changed the primary key for `Salary`.  I guessed you didn't really want `EmpNo` as both primary and foreign key, so I used an autonumber field, *uid*, as primary key.  You'll have to fix that if I guessed wrong.

```vb
Dim strDdl As String
strDdl = "CREATE TABLE Salary" & vbCrLf & _
    "(" & vbCrLf & _
    "uid COUNTER PRIMARY KEY," & vbCrLf & _
    "EmpNo CHAR (6)," & vbCrLf & _
    "OfficeNo CHAR (4)," & vbCrLf & _
    "SalaryAmount DECIMAL (7, 2)," & vbCrLf & _
    "CONSTRAINT FKEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee(EmpNo)" & vbCrLf & _
    ");"
Debug.Print strDdl
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

And finally, this answer was to show you how you can use `DECIMAL` in a `CREATE TABLE` if you really want it.  However, it seems to me that `CURRENCY` would be the natural choice for a `SalaryAmount` field.